# Debugging a curses.h application? (AppCode)

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, linker, curses, appcode

I've been using the JetBrains IDE **AppCode** for a few years now, but I've never had the need to pass command line arguments to the debugger before. As you probably know, in order to link the compiler with the necessary curses files, you have to include `-lcurses` in the command line to compile the program. The issue I'm having is that I'm not exactly sure how to correctly pass this parameter to the debugger. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A debugger should not need the list of libraries since all of the relevant information about linked libraries exists in the executable which is being debugged.